# Images a bit broken in Typo3

Tags: image, image-processing, typo3

I have first experienced troubles with pictures when their size has been generated as 0 when inserted for example as a picture content element. Now I have started using RTE and when I try to insert a picture a windows pops up up with the list of available pictures but when I select one, the popped up windows goes blank and never recovers. When I deploy the app on the server everything works fine. What might be wrong with my local environment?

Comment: Not sure if this is at all related to the images, as it's the window that goes blank, so could be anything.. But check your imagemagick and gd versions and paths - if they're the same local and in production.  In production, i've had issues with imagemagick and CageFS conflicting, so there might be many possible factors

Comment: It seems I do not have the imagick installed locally (as opposed to the server). This look looks promising. I am struggling with making imagick work though so I do not know yet if it helps.

Comment: Yes that's why I develop my TYPO3 sites on a "real" webserver ... By the way, Imagick (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) is a php wrapper class for Imagegmagick (and which has some issues too, so it's not always installed by webhosts) and shouldn't be confused with Imagemagick.

Comment: Ah here's a guy installing TYPO3 with imagemagick locally (in german) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ugh7qekxyw

Comment: @Urs I can't see any reference from your link to Imagegmagick. Furthermore at http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick it explicitly says it is a wrapper to ImageMagick.

Comment: Just sayin' that imagick != Imagemagick, which is often not obvious.